# Convert a For loop to a function python and function argument clarification

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop

I'm following this video `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rN2NNUqN1Fc` for revision before a python exam and at 25 minutes in, he converts a `while loop` into a `for loop`, so I thought I'd try to convert that `for loop` into a `function` but I've hit a snag.

Here's the original for loop:

```
for row in range (5,0, -1):
    for item in range(row,0, -1):
        print(item*2, end =' ')
    print("")
```

And what I've tried:

```
def triangle(row):
    row = 0
    for row in range (5,0, -1):
        for item in range(row,0, -1):
            newrow = row +1
            return item*2
            return newrow
            return triangle(newrow)

newrow = triangle
print(triangle(newrow))
```

I'm not getting any errors but it just prints out 10.

I'd appreciate clarification on the arguments as I'm not fully sure what the `5,0, -1` are doing in `for row in range`
and the `row, 0, -1` in `for item in range`

What i think is the `5` is the `range 0-5` which gets multiplied by 2 when `returning items*2`
the `0` is how many `rows` get printed I think and the `-1` is how many numbers get put in a `row` -1 each time there's a new row?

Then with the item in range -> I get a bit lost

Also I feel there's a way to do this by decreasing from 10 in steps of 2 that might be better? Not really important but an alternate way of iterating this would nice to know.

I've read over and watched videos on creating functions and defining variables and creating loops but it doesn't get any clearer, i think I need an ELI5 as I'm feeling pretty dumb over it.

Comment: `return()` exits the function and does not continue iteration.

Comment: _he converts a while loop into a for loop, so I thought I'd try to convert that for loop into a function but I've hit a snag._ I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You aren't *replacing* a loop with a function, no? Have you checked the documentation for `range()` ? Have you tried stepping through the program on paper? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/.

Comment: @AMC I'm trying create a function from the for loop. That's the thing, I feel like it should work and I'm not getting an error just the output `10` rather than the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

To turn it into a function you insert the code within the function:

```
def triangle():
    for row in range (5,0, -1):
        for item in range(row, 0, -1):
            print(item*2, end =' ')
        print("")
triangle()
```

The (5,0,-1) is to give you the value from 5 to 1, descending. To see this, run the code below:

```
for row in range(5,0,-1):
    print(row)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried to run the top code but it doesn't print anything. So I changed the indentation and tried to call the function like this 

`def triangle():
    for row in range (5,0, -1):
        for item in range(row, 0, -1):
            print(item*2, end =' ')
print(triangle())`

and I'm getting this output:
`10 8 6 4 2 8 6 4 2 6 4 2 4 2 2 None`